# How can i combine the effects of options passed in the command line on strings?

Tags: c, string

I have a function that receives some flags and based on these flags it formats the line to be printed as output. The problem is, these flags are independent of each other. In other words, the output can be formatted as many ways as there are combinations of these flags.

There 3 flags: bflag, nflag and sflag. If bflag is 1, nflag is overidden. But we can have b and s at the same time (or n and s), and both manipulate the output line in its own way. How can i handle this without nesting all the possibilites in if statements ( the only way i can think of) ?

Here's the function that receives the non-formatted string and the flags:

```
void outputLine(int *index, char buffer[], int bflag, int nflag){ //processes the options passed in the command line to create the output
  if (nflag){
    indexedLineout(index, buffer);
  }
  else if (bflag){
    bprint(index, buffer);
  }
  else{//no options
    printf("%s", buffer);
  }
}
```

And here's indexedLineout():

```
void indexedLineout(int *index, char buffer[]){//adds an index to the beginning of the line
  printf ("%*d\t%s", 6, *index, buffer);
  (*index)++;//increment the index
}
```

I dont think it is relevant to show bprint() as it has a very sinmilar behaviour to indexedLineOut().

If i want to add the s flag i mentioned above, that basically does not print anything if the previous output was an empty line, and make sure that it also works in conjunction with the other flags, in other words, make sure it can print numbered lines but not adjacent empty ones,  how can i achieve that?

Comment: So you need formatting functions for each flag, returning formatted string (not printing). Then you pass that string to the next formatting function. After you processed each flag, you can print the output.

Comment: This question is too vague for me. I'd have to see the uncompressed code to see how to simplify it.

Comment: The details of the formatting to be performed under control of the various options actually *does* matter in this case.  Ideally, you would be able to apply their effects independently of each other, so that you need only one function per option instead of a separate one for each combination of options.  The `indexedLineout()` behavior looks promising in that regard, but it's not clear whether the other formatting will play nicely with that and with each other.

Comment: Just for our understanding: What should happen if the caller sets all three flags? Are all flags are booleans, so we have in total eight variants?

Comment: @user5329483 b numbers all non-empty lines, n numbers all lines and s removes all empty adjacent empty lines. so if all the flags are set, n is overridden by b and it produces an ouput in which all the non empty lines are numbered and there can only be a maximum of 1 empty line between each line (effect of s)

Comment: What exactly does it mean to number all non-empty lines? Does `"a\n\nb\n"` become `"1 a\n\n2 b\n"` or `"1 a\n\n3 b\n"`?

Comment: Your biggest problem, it seems to me, is the 'memory' necessary to know whether the last line was blank.  It is probably easiest if the calling code keeps track of whether the last line was empty or not, and passes a `prev_empty` flag too.  For the rest, it is up to you whether 3 or more separate variables are more appropriate than a bit mask.  But you end up having to handle the combinations appropriately.  What's appropriate depends on the context.  The outline you have is not bad.  An alternative is to use separate functions and save the appropriate one in a function pointer and use that.

Comment: Should  'sflag' act as a filter to replace multiple empty lines with a single one? And then feed its result in a 'bflag' and 'nflag' processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There 3 flags: bflag, nflag and sflag. If bflag is 1, nflag is
>   overidden. But we can have b and s at the same time (or n and s), and
>   both manipulate the output line in its own way. How can i handle this
>   without nesting all the possibilites in if statements ( the only way i
>   can think of) ?

You have two separate formatting functionalities controlled by three options, in a particular way that should be relatively clean to handle.  You should be able to simply iterate over the lines, and for each one:

1. **Compress blank lines if appropriate (flag s)**.  If the line is blank, the previous was also blank, and the `s` flag is in effect, then skip this line.  Otherwise,
2. **Print the line number if appropriate (flags n,b)**.

   - if the `n` flag is in effect and `b` is not, then print the line number, else
   - if the `b` flag is in effect and the line is not blank then print the line number.
3. **Print the line itself**.

I don't think I'd even split that up into separate functions, but if you do then I'd recommend choosing functions that fit cleanly into that scheme.

Comment: I think you need to switch the actions associated with `b` and `n` in your algorithm.

Comment: No, you swapped `b` and `n` themselves. Now you also need to switch their order.